# Galvanized Gutters Required For Dormer With Rubber Roof?

Tags: roof, gutters, contractors

I have a long dormer and currently there is no gutter, water just runs off and is starting to seep into my basement. I got an estimate to install gutters on  the dormer and the contractor said that because the roof on the dormer is rubber (I have shingles on the rest of the slanted parts of the roof) that the only type of gutters than can be installed are galvanized and they are 7x the cost of regular aluminum gutters.

I'm wondering if this contractor is taking me for a ride or not.

In summary, is it OK to install standard aluminum gutters on a rubber roof? If so, are galvanized better and would this guy tell me galvanized is the only way?

Comment: That certainly smells like male bovine food byproduct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This study](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijc/2012/496960/) demonstrated not only no increased corrosion near an EDPM o-ring on an aluminum sample after 4 years immersion in salt water, but actually a lack of corrosion where the o-ring protected the aluminum from contact with salt water. The unprotected surface of the aluminum did corrode, but that's normal (it's salt water, not rainwater...)

EDPM is the normal material of rubber roofs. Rubber roofs are often secured with aluminum edge trim.

Find another gutter guy; this one's a scam artiste.

Comment: Are there any other reasons this guy might be saying its got to be galvanized?

Comment: Well, he could believe that it's needed with rubber roofing. Common knowledge and all that...

Comment: @user3757614 Would it be fair to say that this used to be required, based on old knowledge/tools/equipment.